# How do I get value from html input control?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to get the value from html input control and send it to my controller on my image click event. Here is the code snippet to capture an email ID and send it to another view.

```
    <div id="div1">
            <a href="<%= Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new {strEmailAddress = ????? }) %>">
              <img  alt="sign up" src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/media/signup_btn.png") %>" border="0" /></a>
       </div>
<input name="Email address" type="text" value="Email address" />
```

How do I get the value from this input element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//try something like this using a javascript function
    <html>     
      <head>
         <script>
           function WhatsMyValue(field)
           {
               alert("field:" + field.value);
           }
         </script>
     </head>
     <body>
         <form name="f1">
             <input type="text" onkeyup="WhatsMyValue(this);" name="text1">           
         </form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

link JQuery here

```
<script>alert($("#myCon").html());</script>
<input type="text" id="myCon" name="text1">
```